# How to do patchEntity in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, merge, save, cakephp-3.0

Hi I'm making a webpage to get phone number from registerer and make random number as a pin number to save in DB.
and I want to show registerer to enter the random number.

So I made these code.

```
class RegistersController extends AppController{

    public function index()
    {
        $random = rand(11111,99999);
        $register = $this->Registers->newEntity($this->request->data);
        if($this->Registers->save($register)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The Phone number has been sent.');
            $reg = $this->Registers->patchEntity($random);
            $this->Registers->save($reg);
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'certnum']);
        }
        $this->set(compact('register'));
    }
}
```

But somehow It makes fatal error which I have no idea what to do?

Do i have to the random number into array with certain id number or something?

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: what line causes the fatal error? what is the error description? Are you in debug mode?

Comment: The line with $reg = $this->Registers->patchEntity($random); caused fatal error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Back to developer school:** When asking for help and describing a problem **always** post the *complete* error message, any warning, notice, stack trace and other relevant debug output as well.

I *guess* the error message I don't know is related to the fact that you try you pass an invalid data type to [patchEntity()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_patchEntity). It expects an **array**, you are passing an **integer**, because that's what rand() generates. Put the integer in whatever array structure you expect and it should work.

Comment: Thanks I was struggling to find the way to resolve this problem and I found the answer. I should've declare the             $reg = $this->Registers->patchEntity($register, $rand);
 to put random number into an array structure. Thank you for your advise.